# Pyspark cluster mode exception - Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number

Tags: pyspark, airflow, hadoop-yarn

In apache airflow, I wrote a PythonOperator which use pyspark to run a job on yarn cluster mode. I initialize the sparksession object as follows.

```
    spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("test python operator") \
    .master("yarn") \
    .config("spark.submit.deployMode","cluster") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

However, when I run my dag, I get an Exception.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 983, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/catfish/dags/dags_dag_test_python_operator.py", line 39, in print_count
    spark = SparkSession \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 186, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 371, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 128, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 320, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 105, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

I also set *PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS*, but it doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install spark on your ubuntu container.

```
RUN apt-get -y install default-jdk scala git curl wget
RUN wget --no-verbose https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-2.4.6/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
RUN tar xvf spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
RUN mv spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7 /opt/spark
ENV SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
```

And unfortunately you cannot run spark on yarn with PythonOperator. I suggest you to use [SparkSubmitOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator/index.html) or [BashOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/bash.html).

Comment: I use SparkSubmitOperator and my problem is solved!

Comment: Great that it helped! Pyspark has weird issue on this!

Comment: As you mentioned it has some problems regarding PythonOperator for running spark yarn cluster mode.